# How return value from insert sql statment that data inserted or not

Tags: c#, sql

```
IF (@Mode='Insert')
Begin
If NOT Exists (Select ProductName From dbo.tblProduct WHERE ProductName = @ProductName) 
Insert into tblProduct
(
ProductName ,
ProductCode )
Values
(

@ProductName ,
@ProductCode )
```

this is my insert code now using C# i want to tackle the out put i mean that code is inserted or not i.e., i want to tackle these three thing
1. code insert succefully
2. Product name already exsit
3. sql exception error occured

while my C# code is

```
int output= objProduct.Insert()
```

what will output variable will return in according to above three condition

Comment: Brief your c# code behind more...What objProduct represents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to track result of stored procedure

```
DECLARE @result INT
IF (@Mode='Insert')
Begin
    If NOT Exists (Select ProductName From dbo.tblProduct WHERE ProductName = @ProductName) 
     BEGIN
          Insert into tblProduct
          (ProductName ,ProductCode )
          Values
          (@ProductName ,@ProductCode )

          SET @result=1
     END
     ELSE
         SET @result=0
End

SELECT @result
```

In C# , get the value returned and display alert box

```
int output= objProduct.Insert();
if (output.ToString() == "1")
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Data Inserted Successfully');</script>", false);
}
else
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Can not be enter duplicate values.');</script>", false);
}
```